# Manual JOIN on CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm trying to do manual join because I expected to get better query result than CakePHP did.

This is my controller's coding

```
$this->ClinicWishList->contain();
$this->set('recordSets', $this->ClinicWishList->find('all', array(
  'fields' => array('ClinicWishList.*', 'ApplicantIssue.issue_desc', 'User.nickname', 'User.role'),
  'joins' => array(
    array(
      'table' => 'applicant_issues',
      'alias' => 'ApplicantIssue',
      'type' => 'left outer',
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('ClinicWishList.issue_id' => 'ApplicantIssue.id')
    ),
    array(
      'table' => 'users',
      'alias' => 'User',
      'type' => 'left outer',
      'foreignKey' => false,
      'conditions' => array('ApplicantIssue.user_id' => 'User.id')
    )),
    'conditions' => array('ClinicWishList.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')),
    'order' => 'ClinicWishList.created DESC'
  )));
```

CakePHP produced the SQL like this.

[image]

There is no error but I got empty result from the joined table like this.

[image]

I copied the SQL and tried to execute on the GUI tool, I got this warning.

[image]

How to modify coding in CakePHP to get SQL like

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
'conditions' => array('ClinicWishList.issue_id' => 'ApplicantIssue.id')
```

to:

```
'conditions' => array('`ClinicWishList`.`issue_id` = `ApplicantIssue`.`id`')
```

and change this line:

```
  'conditions' => array('ApplicantIssue.user_id' => 'User.id')
```

to:

```
  'conditions' => array('`ApplicantIssue`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`')
```